# How to solve for $t$ in $16((t^2-2)^2-2)-4(t^2-2)-2t=235$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quadratics

How can I solve for $t$ in
$$16((t^2-2)^2-2)-4(t^2-2)-2t=235$$
?

Can I solve it somehow like a quadratic equation?

N.B. In the equation I need to solve, $t$ is given by $t\equiv 2^\frac{x}{4}+\frac{1}{2^\frac{x}{4}}$.

Comment: Hint: expand the polynomial in $t$ and look for a rational root. Or, for a shortcut, just observe that $x=4$ is a solution to the original equation.

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can expand to $$16 t^4 - 68 t^2 - 2 t - 195 = 0$$

and look for rational roots by [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). Once you find a root you can factor to a cubic.

A an alternative you can solve completely by the general solution [Quartic Equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticEquation.html)

Comment: `and solve completely by the general solution Quartic Equation` Once you found the rational root, the other factor is a cubic. You don't actually need to solve it *completely* in this case, just show that it has no real root $\ge 2$ since $t= 2^{x/4}+1 / 2^{x/4} \ge 2\,$, which is easier to verify.

Comment: yes of course, I meant as an alternative! Thanks!

Comment: To completely solve the remaining cubic equation, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yY09LFn06nc) is a video on it.